# Prove: in geometric sequence ($0\ <\ r\ <\ 1$) the ratio between a term and the sum of all following terms doesn't depend on the location of that term

Tags: sequences-and-series

Another question from my math finals, this time we were working with a geometric sequence. We were asked several questions about a specific sequence, but then the last question was this: prove that in every geometric sequence in which the common ratio $r$ is defined in $0<r<1$, the ratio between a certain term and the sum of all following terms does not depend on the location of that term within the sequence.

My initial approach was to take the sequence in which the first term is $1$ and the common ratio is $\frac{1}{2}$, so the sequence is: $$1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16},...$$
I checked what happens with the first term: $$\frac{a_1}{\frac{a_2}{1-r}}=\frac{1}{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}}=1$$
Then proceeded to try the second term: $$\frac{a_2}{\frac{a_3}{1-r}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}}=1$$
And the third term: $$\frac{a_3}{\frac{a_4}{1-r}}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{\frac{1}{8}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}}=1$$
Obviously this shows that it's true for the first three terms, but when trying to find the "general term equation," I got: $$\frac{a_n}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{1-r}}=a_n\left(\frac{1-r}{a_{n+1}}\right)=\frac{a_n\left(1-r\right)}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{r}\left(1-r\right)=\frac{1}{r}-1=\frac{1-r}{r}$$
Does this mean it's true and I proved it? If not then how do I go on from here?

Comment: Yes - your final line is the sort of thing you were expected to produce

Comment: Note $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=r$ so you can speed up the calculations.

Comment: @zwim you're right, I'll edit it right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the answer $$\frac{a_n}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{1-r}}=\frac{1-r}{r}$$ is indeed correct and proves that it's true, because you can plug in the said common ratio $r = \frac{1}{2}$ and it would be equal to $1$, just like it was in every specific term I tried.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed you proved it in the final calculation,for the simple reason that your final expression has no dependence on $n$ the position of a certain term

As a side note, I'm assuming this is a highschool final exam, so you aren't expected to be proficient in rigorous proof writing, but  your statement "obviously this shows that it is true" is not true at all, you only proved 3 specific cases of infinitely many, you might have noticed that the dependence of the position cancels out somehow, but this was an intuitive realization and without making it explicit, you won't be able to convince other mathematicians of your result unless they too have the same intuition, and as problems get more complicated and less and less people have the precise knowledge you have, this becomes problematic because perhaps no one has the same intuition, and even more likely, perhaps the intuition is wrong

To find a way to formalise your idea, read up about "proof by induction"

Comment: Yeah, I meant to write true for the first 3 terms. I fixed it now. Would I be able to prove this using induction?

Comment: I think it should be possible, but probably also an overkill

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the help